# Get a value before implicit transformation is performed in class-transformer

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I am trying to convert a GET parameter to a boolean value.
I am using NestJS with class-validator and class-transformer.
I have set `enableImplicitConversion` to `true` in the validator pipe options.

```
class ExampleDto {
  @Transform(value => value === 'true')
  prop1: boolean;
}
```

Now the issue is, the GET parameter's value is always string, so the implicit transformation will always convert it to `true`. I can prevent it by running a custom logic, but the implicit transformation is being performed before i can run any custom logic (i.e. the @Transform decorator).

Is there any way to get the value before it has been transformed?

or, Is there any other way I can achieve what I am trying to achieve? (eg. disable implicit conversion for a property, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

The function we pass to `@Transform` decorator takes 3 parameters. One of them is the original object (without transformation).

Answer (score 0):

you need to implicitly check whether the Boolean string is true or false. if that doesn't match the condition return the original string value.

```js
class ExampleDto {
  @IsBoolean()
  @Transform(({ value} ) => value === 'true' ? true : value === 'false' ? false : value)
  prop1: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @barley said the "obj" parameter it solves your problem.

So the "Transform" decorator will be like this:

```js
class ExampleDto {
  @Transform(({ obj }) => JSON.parse(obj.prop1))
  prop1: boolean;
}
```